# 2006 Toyota Solara Not Starting on First Turn

Tags: toyota, battery, starting, troubleshooting, solara

I'm new here so I apologize ahead of time if I leave anything out or post improperly.

I have a 2006 Toyota Solara SLE V6 3.3L- I've been having issues starting it on the first go- whether the engine is cold or not, it doesn't seem to matter. 
I'll turn the key and it cranks and tries to start, but doesn't. I'll wait 2 seconds, try again and it usually starts right up. Once it took 3 turns before it started but never more.

Doesn't overheat, doesn't show other noticeable symptoms, doesn't stall or hesitate in traffic or at high speeds. Lights aren't dim, no surging, all fluids are fine- I don't know what to think.

Had some battery issues this past weekend during a cold snap- car was down to 9V seemingly overnight- Never had this happen with the actual battery- it didn't turn or click or anything, it was just dead. I didn't drive it often because I was on winter break (maybe 20mi a week for the past 4 weeks), did a deep charge and it worked again. Parasitic drain of (.13), took it to Walmart to get a load tester on it and it tested fine. We cleaned blue copper crystals off the terminals, but it seemed to have no effect, positive or otherwise.

Intermittent starting is still a problem, but now it seems to have a weak start too.

I'm here scratching my head because I have no idea what it could me. My dad thinks it might be a combo of the crankshaft position sensor going bad and it not being driven enough to charge the battery, but it doesn't have any other symptoms of a crankshaft sensor going bad. Any advice or experience anyone has to offer will be gratefully received.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Sounds very much like a weak battery (and/or bad cell) - get it checked at a shop. Cold conditions will expose  weak batteries.

Comment: @mike65535 Appreciate it - I'll probably get the battery checked again soon